# Java print part of an Array (String)?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a list of accounts in java printed like

```
username,password
```

I also have a list of usernames separate. I am want to be able to extract specific data from the array and display it in the console like this:

```
account.find
SYSTEM: Enter Username: hello123
SYSTEM: hello123,pass123
```

I guess I'm asking, to sum it up, how to search an array for a value (username) and then print the corresponding value from a different array.

Comment: Try to use a HashMap where key is username and value is password.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a `Map` might better suit your needs.  Consider the following snippet:

```
Map<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
userMap.put("hello123", "pass123");
```

Then you can lookup usernames via:

```
String username = "hellow123";
String password = userMap.get(username);
```

Comment: To add to this point, you can also check if the username exists (it seems you are taking input from somewhere for the username) by using `userMap.containsKey(username);`. (If it doesn't exist you can handle that situation, for example, by printing out a message saying the username doesn't exist.)

Comment: @yitzih Good point, but if the OP be certain that there would never be a `null` username, then he could just rely on the value `null` indicating that a username be not present.

Answer (score 0):

There is such a collection which could be useful in your case - and it is called HashMap. You would use username as a key and password as the value.

Comment: Any `Map` would do. A `HashMap` is just a specific implementation of a `Map`.

Comment: @yitzih you are right, I just wanted to point a concrete example of a Map.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use an array to store the accounts, use a `List` in order get the index of the username, which you can use to get the associated password.

```
int index = Arrays.asList(usernames).indexOf(user);
if (index !=-1) {
    String pass = passwords[index];
}
```